# Is the MathJax gem really useful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mathjax

I would like to integrate math equations in a Rails project. I see that there exist a well-maintained MathJax gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/mathjax-rails/versions/2.5.1). On the webpage of this gem, there is a section called "Why bother with another gem?", which argues mainly that MathJax is huge and makes it difficult to manage the project when it is entirely installed in a subdirectory of a rails project. However, on the MathJax webpage (http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html) I see that MathJax is available through a CDN, so I guess there is no need for downloading its source into the Rails project (maybe the gem was made at a time when it was necessary to download MathJax?).

So my question is: is there an advantage that I am missing, of using the gem rather than defining my own few helpers to get MathJax from the CDN and configure it for my need?

Comment: You are asking us to give our opinion whether something you need is useful. We don't know your needs except you want to integrate math equations. We don't know your programming ability or expertise. You need to decide if you want to work on one or the other, try implementing it, and when you run into problems ask about that specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all things work, I think the CDN is the best and simplest way. They give instructions, it's free, it should reduce the performance and deployment cost of the library on your app, and if anything doesn't work it'll be easier to get help since you haven't done anything framework-specific.

However, using a CDN adds a partial failure mode to your app: what happens when your app server returns your HTML, but the CDN is down or unreachable for the MathJax assets? Your users will see the TeX code instead of the rendered equations.

This is pretty unusual, but can happen. Sometimes the CDN is broken, other times the [user's ISP screws up their DNS](http://bt.com) to the [CDN](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) but not to your app.

Whether this is a risk worth defending against depends on your app, your users, etc.

You can avoid it by hosting mathjax yourself (app server or CDN) but it'll be more work to set up, and if you're using a CDN at all you can still get these partial failures.

If you really want the equations to render every time your app serves a page take a look at the server side rendering options (nodejs) added to [MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-node) and KaTeX recently. I'm not aware of a gem bundling this up yet for rails but it'd be cool to have. There's a [mathjax node server/service](https://github.com/tiarno/mathjax-server) you could send requests to from rails (cache the requests), but that'll complicate deployment if you're used to having a single app. There's also someone [calling KaTeX through execjs](https://github.com/drewsberry/jekyll-katex-block).